# How to use clang to cross-compile to different <arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<env> on Mac M3?

Tags: c, macos, clang, cross-compiling

I am looking to play with [cross compilation in clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html), and tried several commands so far, like this one (on a Mac M3):

```
clang -isysroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` --target=aarch64-pc-freebsd quicksort.c
```

The quicksort.c code is just:

```
// Quick sort in C

#include <stdio.h>

// function to swap elements
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}

// function to find the partition position
int partition(int array[], int low, int high) {

  // select the rightmost element as pivot
  int pivot = array[high];

  // pointer for greater element
  int i = (low - 1);

  // traverse each element of the array
  // compare them with the pivot
  for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= pivot) {

      // if element smaller than pivot is found
      // swap it with the greater element pointed by i
      i++;

      // swap element at i with element at j
      swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }
  }

  // swap the pivot element with the greater element at i
  swap(&array[i + 1], &array[high]);

  // return the partition point
  return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) {
  if (low < high) {

    // find the pivot element such that
    // elements smaller than pivot are on left of pivot
    // elements greater than pivot are on right of pivot
    int pi = partition(array, low, high);

    // recursive call on the left of pivot
    quickSort(array, low, pi - 1);

    // recursive call on the right of pivot
    quickSort(array, pi + 1, high);
  }
}

// function to print array elements
void printArray(int array[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%d  ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

// main function
int main() {
  int data[] = {8, 7, 2, 1, 0, 9, 6};

  int n = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

  printf("Unsorted Array\n");
  printArray(data, n);

  // perform quicksort on data
  quickSort(data, 0, n - 1);

  printf("Sorted array in ascending order: \n");
  printArray(data, n);
}
```

It keeps giving this error:

```
quicksort.c:3:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated
```

The reason for adding `-isysroot` was because of [this thread](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/cant-build-clang-and-libc-on-macos/67868/4).

Running `clang quicksort.c` without the `--target` option compiles file without error. Tried a variation of the target from `--target=x` to `-target x` and same error:

```
clang -isysroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -target aarch64-pc-freebsd quicksort.c
```

Is it possible to get cross-compilation working with clang on the latest mac? I would like to play around with inspecting the various mach-o / elf / etc. formats and how they encode the machine code differently.

The `xcrun` command output is this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk
```

And clang version:

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
```

Comment: I'd try `--sysroot`. `-isysroot` sounds like something that only influences include paths, so not enough for linking (but I could be wrong). Can you show the contents of `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Using `--sysroot` gives a bunch of different errors https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/ec67c2f76e4f5a576148f816f143da6c. `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` gives `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk`.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you show the contents of that directory?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/ec67c2f76e4f5a576148f816f143da6c?permalink_comment_id=4828952#gistcomment-4828952